# Compare elements between two lists - Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, recursion

This is probably a stupid question, but I've been stuck on this problem for some hours now.. I have made a genetic algorithm but thought that I could try to improve it a bit. I want to make a fitness function that compare two lists of digits and returns a value. If both lists contains a number that is the same and are in the same "place" the function should return + 2. If the lists contains a number that is the same but in the wrong place it should return + 1.

I've made two different functions which both fulfill one of these tasks, but I can't manage to incorperate them into one function. Here are the functions:

```
samePlace _ [] = 0
samePlace [] _ = 0
samePlace (x:xs) (y:ys)
    | x == y = (sP xs ys) + 2
    | otherwise = sP xs (ys)
```

This function returns +2 for every digit that is the same and is in the right place.

```
notSamePlace [] _ = 0
notSamePlace _ [] = 0
notSamePlace (x:xs) (ys)
    | elem x (ys) = (notSamePlace xs ys) + 1
    | otherwise = (notSamePlace xs ys)
```

This function returns + 1 is one of the digits in the first list exists in the second list.

The problem I got is that the same-place function requires to split up the two lists and go through them one digit at a time to compare them while the not-the-same-place function needs to keep the second list intact without splitting it up in a head and tail. Would be so thankful if someone could point me in the right direction on how to go about this problem.

Also, my thought was that this function could improve the time it takes to find the solution in the genetic algorithm. If my solution is to find the string "hello world", my thought is that an individual with the gene "leolh owdrl" should have more fitness than a gene that looks like "hFz%l r0M/z". In my program so far the first gene would have a fitness value of 1 (because the 'space' is the only character in the same place as the targets characters) but the second gene has the 'h' and the 'space' right so it would be given a fitness value of 2. Is this a good thought or not?

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Write a function which takes two lists `(as,bs)` and returns `(c,as',bs')` where `c` is the number of letters which are in the same and in the same position and `as'` and `bs'` are `as` and `bs` with those common letters removed.

Comment: In case you would need edit distance as your fitness function: see the https://hackage.haskell.org/package/align package (disclosure: I'm the author).

Comment: Can you see why the `notSamePlace` function here will be quite slow for long strings? Can you think of a way to use an auxiliary data structure to help? Hint: you can find two sensible options in the [`containers`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers) package. One of them is more obviously applicable; the other is actually faster.

Comment: "the same-place function requires to split up the two lists [..], while the not-the-same-place function needs to keep the second list intact without splitting it up in a head and tail." Tip: you can use the as-pattern, for example `list@(x:xs)` where `list` will give you the whole list, `x` the head and `xs` the tail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below function uses `zip` to index every character, which allows to pass the full second list into recursive calls.

```
places :: String -> String -> Int
places _ [] = 0
places [] _ = 0
places xs ys = zippedPlaces (zip xs [1..length xs]) (zip ys [1..length ys])

zippedPlaces :: [(Char, Int)] -> [(Char, Int)] -> Int
zippedPlaces [] _ = 0
zippedPlaces (x:xs) ys =
    let match = filter (\(num, i) -> fst x == num) ys
    in case match of
        [] -> zippedPlaces xs ys
        (a:_) -> (if snd a == snd x then 2 else 1) + zippedPlaces xs ys
```

Comment: Thank you Kapol for your answer! Did not even consider that you could use the zip function for this... Sometimes you just need a new perspective to tackle the problem with. Thanks again! :)

Comment: ```*Main Data.Map Data.List> places "Hello" "Hel"
7
```
Doesn't look clever

Answer (score 0):

Assumes that no list contains duplicates:

```
place [] _ = 0
place _ [] = 0
place (x:xs) (y:ys) = place xs ys +
  if x == y then 1 else (if elem x ys then 2 else 0) + (if elem y xs then 2 else 0)
```